# Ionic responsive multi container grid layout

Tags: ionic-framework, grid, responsive, ion-grid

## Problem

I wanted to create a 3 containers, one being the main big container which will take up most of the screen, and the others almost positioned as hotbars at the left and bottom.
something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlyuS.png).

## What i've tried

I have tried the ion grid but it just seems not to work with responsive layout as well as I thought maybe there was a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for these situations, it is a group of native css commands.

Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

This is a quick example of a layout like your image, you can tweak it to serve your purpose and use your research into flexbox to expand it.

html

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="side-bar"></div>
  <div id="other-content">
    <div id="main-content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;  
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#side-bar{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
}

#other-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#main-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/7wj31ucb/69/